# react-native windows authentication ms-graph

Tags: windows, react-native, microsoft-graph-api

I don't seems to find a package that allow the easy implementation of react-native in a Windows app for the authentication of Azure domain user.

I have this cover with react-native-app-auth on iOS and Android. But for Windows it does not seems to have the proper library. I tried to ask there, if people would have an idea but without any luck (https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth/issues/740). I encountered the error (https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth/issues/87) and after looking at the file of the library it is clear that there is no support for Windows.

I looked into MSAL Library but I could not find anything else than a possibility for Single-Page Applications. I found a question that I tried to re-activate on the topic (https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/discussions/2847). Did anybody tried to use the msal-react and manage to use it in a React-Native Windows App? as from the pre-requisite it seems only for SPA (https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-react/README.md#prerequisites).

I need to implement the Sign In option in the React-Native Windows and I believe I have hit a wall in terms of Google search. So I was hoping somebody might have encountered the same issue and found somekind of solution.

I found those two packages :
https://github.com/stashenergy/react-native-msal
It does not seems to support React-Native Windows.
https://github.com/shedaltd/react-native-azure-ad-2
It does not seems to support React-Native Windows.

If anybody has some experience in subject I much appreciate their input.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/shedaltd/react-native-azure-ad-2 seems to be wired towards authentication of apps to the ms-graph, not authentication of multi-tenant users.

It looks like this is a dead-end. I am surprised as Microsoft seems to be supporting the integration of React-Native Apps for Windows and promoting TypeScript... I would have expected that there would be somekind of solution aim at their own cloud API.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).